# Jockey not detecting my ATI IGP Xpress 1150

Tags: 11.04, ati, dell, jockey

Will get to the point,

Fresh Ubuntu 11.04, I tried to edit the appearance settings for Gnome Do 0.8.4, get the error "you must enable compositing" help guides suggested to install Compiz.

Installed compiz fine, but none of the visual effects work either. Help guides and attempted ATI catalyst software I downloaded suggested video card drivers need to be installed.

My problem is how to get Jockey to see my video card needs drivers or find a manual way of installing the drivers?

- OS, Ubuntu 11.04
- Video Card ATI IGP Xpress 1150
- Computer, Dell Inspiron 1501

Any help would be much appreciated as this is starting to bug me. If Ubuntu 11.04 is not supported possibly going back to Ubuntu 10.x might help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps either try reinstalling the mod aliases that jockey uses:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-modaliases
```

That may help you 'see' your driver, and if that does not work perhaps try to manually install the ATI driver in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then that may help you to sort out your compositing using ccsm.